# What would happen if you heat volatile/flammable material in a vacuum?

Tags: home-experiment, heat

Fire is an oxidizing chemical reaction, in the simplest sense it needs oxygen and fuel to burn in order to stay alight. But what reaction would you observe from a flammable substance like gasoline or lighter fluid in a vacuum?

Comment: What kind of boxing match would you observe if one of the fighters failed to appear, yet the referee decided to proceed anyway? Not a very spectacular one, I'd say.

Comment: In a vacuum volatile compounds will *evaporate*. They won't react as there is nothing for them to react with.

Comment: You should look at a video about fires in vacuum by codys lab

Answer (score 1):

If there's any trace of oxygen, and a spark, the vapors would burn like normal.

If there isn't any oxidising agent, it'll just vaporize and stay that way (maybe the vapors will attain equilibrium with the liquid if the vapor pressure is high enough, basically if there's enough liquid to start with).

That's mostly it... Nothing spectacular :)